# I can't reset my password

Tags: linux-mint, grub2

I can't reset my password. I am on grub 2.06 and trying to reset password on Linux Mint 21 / Xfce. But it keeps telling me authentication token manipulation error.

Comment: How are resetting the password? Because in the grub you can press `e` key and configure it to init with `bash` directly. You will enter as root. But I'm not sure if for that version that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mint USB which you can boot from, try this:

1. Insert the USB and boot into the LiveUSB.
2. Once you're in the live environment, open up a terminal, and enter `fdisk -l`

Now, say you have two partitions (e.g. `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`), one of them is the root partition, while the other is the boot partition.

3. **Mount the root partition first** (it should be the biggest one in size) by typing (e.g.) `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`.
4. Mount the boot partition by typing `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot` (it should be the smallest one in size).
5. Chroot into the mountpoint by typing `chroot /mnt`.
6. Once you've chrooted into the desktop's system, type `passwd` and change the password.
7. Unmount the partitions in the reverse order of what you mounted them with the `umount` command.
8. Reboot.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to reset the password on Grub 2.06. You will need to reinstall Mint 21 Xfce to reset the password. Alternatively, you could try booting into a LiveCD and then reset the password.